# duvida banco de dados sql

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

eu quero inserir registro em `DS_ITEM` e o erro que me da é `"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SCD_ITEM_CONTR' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"`. Como posso conseguir fazer esse registro?

```
insert into SCD_ITEM_CONTR (PK_ITEM_CONTR,DS_ITEM,PK_UNIDADE_FORNEC,PK_NAT_DESP,PK_CONTR) values (14,'Java, JavaScript - Contagem Detalhada',1,1,28)
```

sendo `PK_UNIDADE_FORNEC,PK_NAT_DESP,PK_CONTR` chaves estrangeiras

Comment: Se sua chave primária PK_ITEM_CONTR é do tipo identity qual o motivo de você fornecer um valor para ela? Não seria mais prático não informar tal coluna no INSERT e deixar o próprio sistema fazer o controle?

Comment: Era isso mesmo, ja tinha resolvido mas valeu!

Answer (score 1):

A coluna 'SCD_ITEM_CONTR' é uma coluna de identidade, então tem que ativar uma inserção de identidade na tabela, e inserir as especificações de valores na tabela.

Veja se isso resolve:

```
set IDENTITY_INSERT SCD_ITEM_CONTR on

insert into IDENTITY_INSERT 
            (PK_ITEM_CONTR,
             DS_ITEM,
             PK_UNIDADE_FORNEC,
             PK_NAT_DESP,
             PK_CONTR)
     values  (14,
             'Java, JavaScript - Contagem Detalhada',
             1,
             1,
             28)

set IDENTITY_INSERT SCD_ITEM_CONTR off
```

Não é muito recomendado fazer isso, então recomendo que faça em um ambiente de teste antes. Mas não esqueça depois de executar o SET IDENTITY_INSERT SCD_ITEM_CONTR OFF

Mas é isso que resolveria o problema com erro!

Essa opção pode ser ativada apenas para uma única tabela em todo o banco de dados - portanto, se você a deixar ativada para uma tabela, nunca poderá usá-la para outra tabela. Além disso: não é uma opção que deve ser deixada ativada - por padrão, você deve deixar o SQL Server manipular valores de identidade - destina-se apenas como uma medida de último recurso para casos muito específicos - não é uma opção de uso geral a ser ativada ou desativada.

Comment: Mateus Venancio, poderia validar e marcar a resposta como correto?